# How to change content inside shortcode without changing its atributes?

Tags: php, regex

Hi i am new in PHP Regex and I want to replace the text inside the shortcode without changing its attributes

e.g

```
$str = "Hi i am a shortcode named [ shortcode id="1" ] and [ shortcode id="2" ]"

desired output:-

"Hi i am a shortcode named **shortcode1** and **shortcode2**"
```

I am trying:

```
$query = '[shortcode id="1"]';
$query = preg_quote($query, '~');
$p = '~((\[shortcode id="(\d*)"\])(?(2).*?\[/shortcode id="(\d*)"\])(?:.*?))*? 
(' . $query . ')~smi';
$s = preg_replace($p, "*shortcode${d*\}*", $str);
```

Please Guid Me

Comment: Try `preg_replace('~\[\s*(shortcode)\s+id="(\d*)"\s*]~', '$1$2', $query)`, see https://regex101.com/r/ej53IT/1 and https://3v4l.org/1Xroi

Comment: So are you looking for `[ shortcode id="1" ]` or `[shortcode id="1"]`?

Comment: @kerbh0lz for `[shortcode id="1"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```php
\[\s*(shortcode)\s+id="(\d*)"\s*]
```

Replace with `**$1$2**`. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ej53IT/2).

**Details**

- `\[` - a `[` char
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(shortcode)` - Group 1: `shortcode`
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `id="` - an `id="` string
- `(\d*)` - Group 2: zero or more digits
- `"` - a `"` char
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `]` - a `]` char.

See the [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/rWhLl):

```php
$re = '/\[\s*(shortcode)\s+id="(\d*)"\s*]/i';
$str = 'Hi i am a shortcode named [ shortcode id="1" ] and [ shortcode id="2" ]';
echo preg_replace($re, '**$1$2**', $str);
// => Hi i am a shortcode named **shortcode1** and **shortcode2**
```